# LINQ GroupBy Clause System.NotSupportedException error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this query and I faced this error when I want to check the date inside the `Min()` Method. Can anyone explain the reason? I just know a little about `Expression<Func>` and `Func<>`.

```
var s2 = md.Tb_order
    .GroupBy(x => x.orderid)
    .Where(x => x.Min(p => p.date > 2))
    .Select(x => x);
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The specified method 'Boolean Min[Tb_order,Boolean](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SqlServer_LinqTest.Tb_order], System.Func`2[SqlServer_LinqTest.Tb_order,System.Boolean])' on the type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because no overload matches the passed arguments.'*

if I check the date outside of the Method it works fine

```
var s2 = md.Tb_order
    .GroupBy(x => x.orderid)
    .Where(x => x.Min(p => p.date) > 2)
    .Select(x => x);
```

**EDITED**

When I see the explanation of the `Where()` method it seems there must be a parameter of `Func<>`. What is the relation between `p.date` and `Func<>` type? Does `p.date` return something of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Apparently `Min(bool)` is not supported by EF query translator, what more explanation do you need?

Comment: is p.date>2 of Bollean type?? So I want to know the reason behind the trsnslation, about expression and Func<>! there must be something EF cannot translate this query.

Comment: Of course `p.date > 2` type is `bool`. It's plain C# rule. Same as `int a = 3; bool b = a > 2;`

Comment: thanks , please see my edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548741(v=vs.110).aspx), Min is 
`Min<TSource, TResult>`.

**TSource**
The type of the elements of source.

**TResult**
The type of the value returned by selector (in this case the min date).

but you are passing a condition there which is not what is expecting, it is expecting **a sequence of values** to determine the minimum value of.

Answering your question 
what is the relation between p.date and Func<> type?

p.date is pointer to the attribute date for your enumerable x which is the value of your group dictionary, group result in dictionary which is `<key,value>`, where key is the order id, and value is a list of orders that have the same group key (order id), so when you are writing `Min(p => p.date)` you are asking linq to get the min date of this sequence (the value list).

so when you are doing this `Min(p => p.date) > 2`  you are comparing the min value (result from min) to 2 which is fine, but when you are passing Min(p => p.date > 2) you are passing something LINQ can't translate as we previously mention it is expecting a sequence of values, not a condition.

**Summary**

if you are doing the right way, you are telling linq to group all orders based on order id, and then exclude the groups where group min date is not more than 2 (you exclude the whole group list). 
maybe this is what you want,

or maybe you want this.

```
var s2 = md.Tb_order
    .Where(x => x.date > 2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.orderid);
```

which will return all orders where date is more than 2, then group them.

This differs from the first one, since the first will ignore all orders belonging to the same id when there is one of them doesn't meet date > 2, but this one will ignore only the ones where date > 2.

Comment: oh my bad, omg this is stupid mistake, I forgot to remove Min. Updated, and thank you for pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain the reason?

`Min()` is an [aggregate function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql). You cannot aggregate on a method - e.g. `p.date > 2`. You can, however aggregate on an expression - e.g. `p.date`.

I assume you're trying to find the order, *HAVING* the minimal `date` which is greater than 2. Indeed, the `Min()` method can find the minimal `date`, but that's it. It can't check other condition(s). To do that, you should restrict your records to include only orders with dates greater than whatever you're interested in, and then do the aggregation:

```
var s2 = md.Tb_order
    .Where(x => x.date > 2)
    .GroupBy(x => x.orderid)
    .Min(x => x.date);
```